# Is this mold on my jack links beef steak?

Tags: food-safety

[image: Shot from outside the pack]

[image: The spots stuck to the inside of the pack]

[image: The White stuff on the corner of one strip]

I've attached a couple of pictures of my just-opened Jack Links beef steak. There are white mushy blobs of something on the inside of the packaging, and when I remove the packaging they mostly stick to the plastic and only in some places do they remain on the beef. They are gel-like to the touch, much like a gel ointment or such thing. I can't really figure out what they smell like, cause the smell of the seasoned beef is too strong.

*Is this mold?* I've read in some places that such things could be salt, but salt wouldn't be mushy to touch.

If it helps I bought this right now on my college campus store. We're in the northeast and it's pretty often rainy and wet here.

Comment: It's hard to tell, but I think that's fat.

Comment: Does fat have the similar mushy characteristics I described?

Comment: Yes. Compare to room-temperature butter.

Comment: Or room temp Crisco or lard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't mold, that's fat. There's a good picture of mold on beef in [this page](http://letsmakesomethingawesome.com/2011/02/dry-aging-beef-at-home/). Beef steaks have lots of fat, what's happened is that the fat on the surface of the meat has gotten squished into the plastic and adhered. It doesn't mean your steak isn't safe to eat, if it smells ok you should be fine.